# Adobe Flash Professional failed to initialize properly (0xc0150002)

Tags: windows-7, adobe-flash

I installed Adobe Flash Professional CS5.5 Trial (Windows 7 32-bit), but I can't launch it.

I get the following error:

[image]

Translated, it says:

> The application failed to initialize properly (0xc0150002). Click on OK to terminate the application.

How can I fix this problem? It seems like I have some problems with my system files, DLLs etc. I've tried running it as an administrator, but it didn't help.

Comment: Are you using a legal copy of Adobe Flash Professional CS5.5 Trial?  Did your trial expire?

Comment: @wizlog Thanx, I've just installed Trial copy from official Adobe site, because I need to use it at once, and after I'll uninstall it.

Comment: Has it been installed for more than 30 days?

Comment: I've installed it about few hours ago.